# Convert SQL Server query to MS Access syntax

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT Dated, AccountID, AccountName, Rate, 
  case (when (Credit-Debit) > 0 then Credit-Debit END) as Credit,
  case (when (Credit-Debit) < 0 then Credit-Debit END) as Debit,
  Balance
FROM TempTrallBalance
```

How can I convert it to Access syntax?

Answer (score 5):

The only issue here is that MS Access has no idea what a `CASE` expression is. Instead, you need to use [`IIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx), e.g.:

```
IIF(Credit-Debit > 0, Credit-Debit, NULL) AS Credit,
IIF(Credit-Debit < 0, Credit-Debit, NULL) AS Debit,
```

BTW [`IIF` is now supported in SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx).

Comment: Access also has the [Switch()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-Function-d750c10d-0c8e-444c-9e63-f47504f9e379) function which more closely matches the `CASE ... WHEN` structure and can be used to avoid large numbers of nested `IIf()` functions.